# Build with parameter option is keep getting unchecked when replay or abort the job - ( build job is created through job dsl groovy script)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, dsl, groovydsl

I have created the a pipeline job with the help of groovy job dsl template, Its a parameterized pipeline job. whenever this pipeline job is replayed or aborted, build with parameter option is getting unchecked and parameter section is removed.

this is the DSL template that I have created to create the job -

```
pipelineJob("folder/subfolder") {
    triggers {
        gitlab{
            triggerOnPush(true)
            triggerOnMergeRequest(true) 
            triggerOnNoteRequest(true)
            triggerOnApprovedMergeRequest(true)
            noteRegex('Jenkins please retry a build')
            }
    parameters {
        gitParameter {
            name('sourceBranch')
            type('BRANCH')
            defaultValue('')
            description('')
            branch('')
            branchFilter('origin/(.*)')  
            tagFilter('*')
            sortMode('NONE')
            selectedValue('NONE')
            useRepository("")
            quickFilterEnabled(false)      
        }

        job("Build Triggers") {
        triggers {
            gitlabPush { 
            buildOnPushEvents(true)
            buildOnMergeRequestEvents(true)
          }
        }
      }
         
    definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        url('<GIT_REPO_URL>')
                        credentials('<CREDENTIAL>')
                        branch('origin/${sourceBranch}')
                    }
                }
            }
            scriptPath("Jenkinsfile")
            }
         }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried to change the dsl template gitParameter section to gitParam, I am still getting the same issue, parameterized option is unchecked automatically and it becomes normal pipeline job.
is it the template issue or issue from the jenkins side ?